# Pass Download URL to Bootstrap Modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-modal

I want to pass file Download URL to **Bootstrap Modal** when I click on link and then on Bootstrap Modal after filling some information like name,emailaddress when I click on footer button I want to download that file.How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I'm right about your question, but you just simply make the button of the modal's footer to trigger the download function. See my sample [demo](http://jsbin.com/zejusobaku/edit?output) of it.

**EDIT**

What I've understand about your question is when the user clicks the link, a modal will then appear and at the modal's footer was the direct download button. Note that on my demo, I made the modal just a prompt confirmation to the user.

**HTML**

```
<!-- Button that acts as a link and triggers the modal to open -->
<button class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Download</button>

<!-- Prompt modal. Notice that this is just a confirmation for downloading the file -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Download</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Do you really want to download the file?</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <!-- The download button -->
        <a href="http://s1.picswalls.com/wallpapers/2014/08/08/scottish-landscape-hd_015751702_152.jpg" download>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">DOWNLOAD</button>
        </a>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">CLOSE</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Read [this](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp) to know more about the `download` attribute.

Comment: I want to pass URL to Bootstrap Modal ? How do I implement that ?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do it. It basically depends on in what format you want to download. Some simple example to download it as `.txt` file is below.

HTML :

```
<textarea>some text here to downlaod</textarea>
<p><a href="#">Export</a></p>
```

javascript :

```
var container = document.querySelector('textarea');
var anchor = document.querySelector('a');

anchor.onclick = function() {
    anchor.href = 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(container.value);
    anchor.download = 'export.txt';
};
```